# CMake and command line arguments

Tags: cmake, command-line-arguments

Why I have specified the following lines for tests in CMakeLists.txt of my project:

```
enable_testing()
set(filesyst_rsc "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test/filesyst-rsc")
add_test(test_filesystem test-filesystem ${filesyst_rsc})
```

and in Visual Studio 2010 the generated project for test_filesystem has no command line arguments specified???

Comment: `add_test()` calls don't result in `.vc[x]proj` files being generated, they aren't targets. You run tests using CTest or through the project `RUN_TEST`

Comment: I know that you can pass command lines to your tests since I do this all the time. Maybe you want to enable the "CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1" environment variable and have your test dump output on failure to debug this.

Comment: @Angew tnx for your explanation, but in reality I generated the VS solution by running CMake on a top level CMakeLists.txt, which contains a series of add_subdirectory() commands for all the subdir of the top level dir (subdirs are submodules). This way in my VS solution I have only an ALL_BUILD project + a list of projects, and no RUN_TEST !!! so I cannot run test through that "special" project, as you suggested. Why I have not obtained a RUN_TEST project, although the CMakeLists.txt file of each submodule (subdir) contains all the list of tests (add_test commands) for the specific submodule?

Comment: To have CMake generate tests, you need to call [`enable_testing()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/enable_testing.html).

Comment: ***Why I have not obtained a RUN_TEST project, although the CMakeLists.txt file of each submodule (subdir) contains all the list of tests (add_test commands) for the specific submodule?*** That is all very strange. I do not recall ever having that problem in the 6+ years that I have used CMake at work. Are you sure you regenerated after adding enable_testing()?

Comment: enable_testing() is present in the CMakeLists.txt of each submodule :( Do I need to specify it in the CMakeLists.txt of the top-level dir? But in the latter I have only a series of add_subdirectory() commands, and no targets specified (all targets are each in CMakeLists.txt of each submodule...)

Comment: @Angew enable_testing is called but in the CMakeLists.txt of each submodule, not in the top-level one, which contains anyway only a series of add_subdirectory() commands. What do I need to do so, according to your experience?

Comment: Add `enable_testing()` to the root CMakeList, because the command enables testing "in the current subdirectory and below." This means that the top-level solution contains `RUN_TEST` only if the top-level CMakeList does `enable_testing()`.

Comment: Perfect, tnx, now it works!! :)